# Primefaces light box does not work in IE8 and below

Tags: java, primefaces, lightbox

I have a code like below, I could able to open a light box in IE9 and see the content in it, but in IE8 and below light box opens but i don't see the date in it.

Below is the code i am trying

```
 <p:lightBox iframe="true" width="650px" height="300px" margin="0 auto" onHide="remote()">
                    <h:outputLink value="datToBeDisplayed.xhtml" title="DESCRIPTION">
                    <h:graphicImage url="../images/someImage.png" style="border:0"/>
                    </h:outputLink>
                </p:lightBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using xhtml for date output. Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support xhtml. The support is for the versions IE9 and later only

Comment: I did added <!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]--> in my head section of my file

Comment: check if your browser is configured to render the intranet sites in compatibility mode. by default, it is, but it can be an issue if it is off